# HTTP 301, 303, or other Redirect with embedded Relative URLs

Tags: java, http, redirect, cdn

I'm working with a CDN and servlet that redirects to the CDN.

The problem with this solution is that we've stored the content in the CDN under a different naming scheme than the original URLs, while some of the content contains relative references.

Those relative references do not resolve at the CDN.

Is there a way to implement the redirect so that the web browser only looks for the original content at the new URL, and continues to resolve relative references against the original URL?